# I want to create a std::function but add args incrementally

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, std-function

I hope some one can help me a little here. I am relatively new to C++ and also to the concept of Templates. 
I need to create a std::function based on some data that I am getting in a list. 
The signature of the function should be according to the data available. I am looking for something like this

```
template <typename ret, typename... Args, typename newArg>
struct typeparser<ret(...Args)>{
    typeparser<ret(...Args)> insertArg(newArg)
    { 
       retrun typeparser <ret(...args, newArg) > ; 
    }
};
```

What I want to do is iterate through a vector of `boost::variant` and then based on the type of value i see, add it to the list of parameters once complete, create a `std:function` and load it from a lib, then execute it. Make any sense?

```
std::vector<boost::varient<int, char, std::string>> list;
arglist = typeparser<int()>;   //all functions have int return, so start with return int and 0 args
for(boost::varient<int, char, std::string> a : list) {
    if(a.type() ==  typeid(int)){
        arglist.addArg(int); // now add int to list of args
    } else 
    if(a.type()== typeid(char)) {
       arglist.add(char);
    } else
    if (a.type()== typeid(bla)) {
        arglist.add(bla);
    }
  } // end for 
//now create the function here 
std::function<arglist> f = //load from library;
```

Does this even seem possible? Maybe I am looking at the problem in the wrong way? Any thing will help at this time. 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This sounds incredibly difficult to achieve. Since every different argument list creates a different type, which must have been compiled in, you need to have anticipated every possible argument list, and create some kind of mapping from argument list to function which you can use at runtime (or your compiler's name mangler may be available to do that bit). I suggest asking about what you're actually trying to achieve first, and maybe a simpler solution will present itself.

Comment: Templates are evaluated (instantiated) at compile time, so you can't change anything at runtime.  I can't see any way, how to achieve this at runtime. There are other mechanisms though, you can do such at runtime.

Comment: Why not have your function take a range (iterator pair) instead? Then all the work can happen at runtime where you know what the parameters are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::function` must have all its parameters specified at compile time -- what you're asking for would require the set of parameters not be known until runtime which is not allowed.

It would be theoretically possible to make what you're proposing by having something like `std::function` that contained a stack of parameters to call or something like that, but I don't believe that there is a portable way to do it.

It sounds like you would be better off asking for a solution to the problem you need this "runtime `std::function`" for.

Comment: ＋1 for hinting at [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I understand, what you mean and yeah, if the compiler wants to know at compile time then there is no way to get past it with this approach. What I am trying to do is extent one of our current libs so that it works over the network ( so in theory RPC) but some of the frameworks I looked at are too complicated, and I thought maybe I could tackle the problem like this. What I tried to achieve is, have the server listen and when a request comes, look at it and get the function by name from the existing lib and invoke it. Any suggestions maybe? (make sense?) Thanks!

Comment: @codeCruncher: If that were possible it would create a huge vulnerability in your application because a malicious client could send `DeleteFileW` or similar. You probably want to look at one of the many existing RPC solutions that use some form of interface definition language and hook it up in your server explicitly. e.g. http://www.grpc.io/ or COM remoting or similar

Comment: @BillyONeal Thanks, that is actually what I have started working on. I stumbled upon zeroC which is intimidating, can'n Proto, which looks kinda nice, I will go through grpc like you suggest, just on the side, (if you already know) can I pass a function pointer as a parameter for a call back at the client side? And when something on the server invokes this callback the client knows. Make sense? If there is something like that?

Comment: @code: No, the address at which the function is located on the server and client are almost certainly going to be different.